Why does the first run of Python requests take so long
I’m using Ollama to generate embeddings and noticed that the first cold run takes 3 times more time when I call API explicitly compared to calling ollama.embeddings() function (that uses the same API):
session = requests.Session()

model = "nomic-embed-text"
prompt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet aliquam urna."

start_time = time.time()
emb2 = ollama.embeddings(model=model, prompt=prompt)['embedding']
print(time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
emb1 = session.post("http://localhost:11434/api/embeddings", json={"model": model, "prompt": prompt}).json()['embedding']
print(time.time() - start_time)

Output:
0.07877588272094727
2.1047933101654053

There is no difference on the server side:
{"function":"launch_slot_with_data","level":"INFO","line":829,"msg":"slot is processing task","slot_id":0,"task_id":78,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345737}
{"function":"update_slots","level":"INFO","line":1834,"msg":"kv cache rm [p0, end)","p0":0,"slot_id":0,"task_id":78,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345737}
{"function":"update_slots","level":"INFO","line":1642,"msg":"slot released","n_cache_tokens":33,"n_ctx":2048,"n_past":33,"n_system_tokens":0,"slot_id":0,"task_id":78,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345737,"truncated":false}
[GIN] 2024/04/05 - 15:35:37 | 200 |     76.8815ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST     "/api/embeddings"
{"function":"launch_slot_with_data","level":"INFO","line":829,"msg":"slot is processing task","slot_id":0,"task_id":81,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345739}
{"function":"update_slots","level":"INFO","line":1834,"msg":"kv cache rm [p0, end)","p0":0,"slot_id":0,"task_id":81,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345739}
{"function":"update_slots","level":"INFO","line":1642,"msg":"slot released","n_cache_tokens":33,"n_ctx":2048,"n_past":33,"n_system_tokens":0,"slot_id":0,"task_id":81,"tid":"80784","timestamp":1712345739,"truncated":false}
[GIN] 2024/04/05 - 15:35:39 | 200 |     65.5866ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST     "/api/embeddings"

Subsequent runs take the same amount of time, so no issues here.
0.022333621978759766
0.02305150032043457

But the question is why it’s so different during the first run. What magic does Ollama use :)?
